# dbDateTimePicker that accepts a Field of type string

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Where can I find a free delphi component dbdatetimepicker that accepts a datafield of type string instead of the usual datetime field. Any help is greatly appreciated. Bty I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't convert the string to a date with strtodate() ?

Comment: Using STRING to hold DATE is a very, very bad idea. You might want to stop looking for a DB component that presents STRING as DATE and start looking for a way to convert all existing dates to the proper format (DATE).

Comment: Sir I have a FoxPro Database that stored date as a string. I don't want to modify all of it and wanted to be able to modify when it needs to be updated and be able to possibly share it with Foxpro where it came from...

Comment: I agree that StrtoDate() would seem to be the most logical solution to your problem

Comment: I agree with Cosmin - storing the string is a bad idea. But, can you not just use a DbMaskEdit?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own component to acheive what you require. You could quite simply inherit or derive from your base class and provide methods to accept and get a string representation of the datetime.